# Missing private sector credit in IFS for Euro-area countries 1998--1999

Tags: data-request, finance, economics

I'm using the IMF International Financial Statistics (IFS) database through their online Query Builder (http://elibrary-data.imf.org/DataExplorer.aspx) to obtain measures of credit by "other depository institutions" to the private sector. I am particularly interested in series `22D__` and `FOSAOEA` for Euro-area countries.

I have noticed that there are missing values in 1998 and/or 1999 for some Euro-area countries in these credit series, coinciding with conversion to the Euro. I print these data below with missing values indicated by `NA`.

Does anyone know where I could obtain these missing values?

I have tried looking at OECD Stat and EuroStat without any luck. For any particular country--year, I only need one of `22D__` or `FOSAOEA` because I would like to combine these into a single variable.

```
       Time.Code Country.Code Country.Label        22D__      FOSAOEA
1       1998          122       Austria           NA           NA
2       1998          124       Belgium           NA           NA
3       1998          132        France           NA           NA
4       1998          134       Germany 4.471874e+12           NA
5       1998          136         Italy 1.224358e+15           NA
6       1998          137    Luxembourg           NA           NA
7       1998          138   Netherlands           NA           NA
8       1998          172       Finland 3.587975e+11           NA
9       1998          174        Greece 1.372146e+13           NA
10      1998          178       Ireland 5.402000e+10           NA
11      1998          181         Malta 1.492264e+09           NA
12      1998          182      Portugal 1.970510e+13           NA
13      1998          184         Spain 7.641700e+13           NA
14      1998          423        Cyprus 7.203981e+09           NA
15      1998          936      Slovakia 4.209860e+11           NA
16      1998          939       Estonia 2.509500e+10           NA
17      1998          941        Latvia 5.822570e+08           NA
18      1998          946     Lithuania 5.602200e+09           NA
19      1998          961      Slovenia 1.086718e+12           NA
20      1999          122       Austria           NA 2.082890e+11
21      1999          124       Belgium           NA 2.187240e+11
22      1999          132        France           NA 1.159879e+12
23      1999          134       Germany           NA 2.391709e+12
24      1999          136         Italy           NA 8.110520e+11
25      1999          137    Luxembourg           NA 8.255403e+10
26      1999          138   Netherlands           NA 4.961740e+11
27      1999          172       Finland           NA 6.548100e+10
28      1999          174        Greece 1.773396e+13           NA
29      1999          178       Ireland           NA 1.099990e+11
30      1999          181         Malta 1.658927e+09           NA
31      1999          182      Portugal           NA 1.336460e+11
32      1999          184         Spain           NA 5.296370e+11
33      1999          423        Cyprus 8.448551e+09           NA
34      1999          936      Slovakia 4.604280e+11           NA
35      1999          939       Estonia 2.667210e+10           NA
36      1999          941        Latvia 6.686860e+08           NA
37      1999          946     Lithuania 6.263900e+09           NA
38      1999          961      Slovenia 1.351184e+12           NA
```

The Global Financial Development Database (GFDD) of the World Bank provides a similar variable called GFDD.DI.01, but this variable is calculated from the IFS and hence is also missing for Euro-area countries in 1998 and 1999. Below is an extract from the GFDD showing the country--years with missing data:

```
     Country.Code year GFDD.DI.01
559           AUT 1998         NA
560           AUT 1999         NA
715           BEL 1998         NA
716           BEL 1999         NA
3367          FRA 1998         NA
3368          FRA 1999         NA
6227          LUX 1998         NA
6228          LUX 1999         NA
7683          NLD 1998         NA
7684          NLD 1999         NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's too late to help you, but maybe others will face the same problem. For 1998 you can find data in the IMFs "International Financial Statistics Yearbook(s)" (if you are at a university your library might have them), but even there data for 1999 is missing. I'm not sure yet why this is the case, but I try to find out, since I want to know too. I think in the end the only possibility to fill these gaps will be interpolation.

It's also a bit strange that the gaps in the online IFS data are longer than those in the (printed) IFS Yearbook(s). Unfortunately there are no hints in the yearbooks why those gaps exist. There are notes for many countries, but they only explain that the establishment of the euro area changed the reporting, no word on the gap in 1999.